# In org-mode, how do I include other .org files from a (main) .org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to place some customization codes in a separate file, and include it from other files later. For example, file `config.org` has a single line `#+MATHJAX: align:"left" mathml:t`. How do I include it in another .org file `abc.org` so that the net-effect is exactly same as I write that `#+MATHJAX` line directly in abc.org?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `#+setupfile: /path/to/config.org` [documented here](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings).

Comment: Documentation link is broken.

Comment: Correct link: https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html

Answer (score 11):

The `#+INCLUDE` directive can [include another file with export options](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html) (but it cannot affect the configuration of the enclosing file, since it is only for export purposes). Use it like:

```
#+INCLUDE: "/path/to/config.org"
```

Comment: manual says "during export". it won't work for directives like "#+startup: overview", right?

Comment: @sindikat Yes, it seems so. I assumed from your example (MathJax) that this would be enough.

Comment: Correct link: https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html